What's the difference between the identifier of a 1-D array and a multi-dimensional array
I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around this. I started going over 1D arrays and pointers, and I understood all these things about it:
Suppose I have:
int a[]{1,2,3,4};

Here, a is the pointer to the first element, and has its address stored in it. We can assign a pointer like so:
int* p = a

and access the elements with *p, *(p+1), *(p+2), etc...
Now with a 2D array, let's say I have:
int b[2][3]{1,2,3,4,5,6}

b is still the address of the first element b[0][0], b[0] and b[1] hold addresses to the corresponding 1D arrays inside b, and I can do:
int* p0 = b[0]
int* p1 = b[1]

So, why isn't b an array of pointers? Why can I not do:
int** p = b

And stemming from the same doubt, why will this not work?

Why does the parameter m[][] not receive the address of m[0][0], and why does m[i][j] not navigate to the expected address?
I've tried googling, and watched a couple of YouTube videos, but nothing helps with this doubt. I would really like to have a clear understanding of what's going on here.

so why isn't b an array of pointers? For the same reason an int isn't a pointer - it's simply not.  Why would you think b is an array of pointers?

"a is the pointer to the first element" - that is incorrect. An array is not a pointer. But an array can decay into a pointer in certain contexts, such as a variable assignment.

b is an array of array not an array of pointers. Your assumption that a is a pointer is also wrong and leads to the wrong conclusion that b is an array of pointer. You can use static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), int[4]>); to confirm that a is indeed an array not a pointer.

@AndrewHenle because (from the text I wrote above), b[0] and b[1] carry the addresses of b[0][0] and b[1][0] respectively? If you do something like int** ptr = new int*[10], and then go through each element, like ptr[i] = new int[10], it essentially is a 2D 10x10 array just on the heap. How does its representation on the stack differ?

I would also highly recommend a good c++ book.

@AbyssH "b[0] and b[1] carry the addresses of b[0][0] and b[1][0] respectively?" - No. b is a true 2D array. b[0] and b[1] are actual arrays, not addresses of arrays. "If you do something like int** ptr = new int*[10], and then go through each element, like ptr[i] = new int[10], it essentially is a 2D 10x10 array just on the heap" - No, that is not a 2D array at all (like b is).  ptr is just a pointer to a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays. b is a single contiguous memory block. ptr consists of 11 separate and distinct memory blocks.

@user12002570 I understand that it's not a pointer, just decays into one, maybe I could've written that part better. I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book and this is the section that threw me in a loop. What is b here then? It does hold the address of the first element of b, same as b[0], but can't be assigned to a pointer, while you can do that for 1D arrays. 2D arrays, are stored contiguously from my understand, i.e. if you have an array a[6] and an array b[2][3] stored in the row-major form, the pointer arithmetic to get to a[3] is the same as b[1][0] (4th elements from the start).

"What is b here then? It does hold the address of the first element of b" - No, it doesn't.  Get that idea out of your head. An array is not an address.  But an address can refer to an array. b is an actual array.  The address of b is the address of the array, which is also the same address as the 1st element of the array. But b itself does not hold an address. "same as b[0], but can't be assigned to a pointer" - Yes, it can. But not the type of pointer that you are expecting. Each element of b is an int[3] array, so you need an int(*)[3] pointer, not an int* pointer.

@RemyLebeau Sorry my bad, you're right it's not a 2D array, the one I created on heap. What I meant to say is that b[0] and b[1] are still address to the first element of the corresponding arrays, right? because when I print b[0] and &b[0][0] their values are the same

"What I meant to say is that b[0] and b[1] are still address to the first element of the corresponding arrays, right?" - No. See my previous comment. "when I print b[0] and &b[0][0] their values are the same" - Yes, because b[0] is an int[3] array that decays into an int* pointer to its 1st element, which is the b[0][0] element

@RemyLebeau But not the type of pointer that you are expecting. Each element of b is an int[3] array, so you need an int()[3] pointer, not an int pointer.... Alright, that helps things. I understand now how I was thinking about it the wrong way. Thanks for the explanation!

@AbyssH Your question's been closed or I'd go into further detail. See here for one of my own replies years ago that might help.

@AbyssH "What is b here then?..." It is an array of array as I said earlier also. You can check this using static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b), int[2][3]>);. See demo
